# How to measure read/cycle or instructions/cycle?

Tags: c++, c, performance, caching, metrics

I want to thoroughly measure and tune my C/C++ code to perform better with caches on a x86_64 system. I know how to measure time with a counter (QueryPerformanceCounter on my Windows machine) but I'm wondering how would one measure the instructions per cycle or reads/write per cycle with respect to the working set.

How should I proceed to measure these values?

Comment: On linux, `valgrind --tool=cachegrind` seems to be a good fit IYAM

Comment: Not only do modern processor execute multiple instructions per cycle, but clock cycle itself varies due to power saving \ dynamic overclock features. But still, you can easily get averages - benchmark a few differently sized data sets, knowing the elapsed time and processor clock you can easily get an approximate estimate without any special tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modern processors (i.e., those not very constrained that are less than some 20 years old) are superscalar, i.e., they execute more than one instruction at a time (given correct instruction ordering). Latest x86 processors translate the CISC instructions into internal RISC instructions, reorder them and execute the result, have even several regster banks so instructions using "the same registers" can be done in parallel. There isn't any reasonable way to define the "time the instruction execution takes" today.

The current CPUs are *much* faster than memory (a few hundred instructions is the typical cost of accessing memory), they are all heavily dependent on cache for performance. And then you have all kinds of funny effects of cores sharing (or not) parts of cache, ...

Tuning code for maximal performance starts with the software architecture, goes on to program organization, algorithm and data structure selection (here a modicum of cache/virtual memory awareness is useful too), careful programming and (as te most extreme measures to squeeze out the last 2% of performance) considerations like the ones you mention (and the other favorite, "rewrite in assembly"). And the ordering is that one because the first levels give more performance for the same cost. *Measure* before digging in, programmers are *notoriously* unreliable in finding bottlenecks. And consider the cost of reorganizing code for performance, both in the work itself, in convincing yourself this complex code is correct, and maintenance. Given the relative costs of computers and people, extreme performance tuning rarely makes any sense (perhaps for heavily travelled code paths in popular operating systems, in common code paths generated by a compiler, but almost nowhere else).

Answer (score 1):

If you are really interested in where your code is hitting cache and where it is hitting memory, and the processor is less than about 10-15 years old in its design, then there are performance counters in the processor. You need driver level software to access these registers, so you probably don't want to write your own tools for this. Fortunately, you don't have to.

There is tools like VTune from Intel, CodeAnalyst from AMD and oprofile for Linux (works with both AMD and Intel processors).

There are a whole range of different registers that count the number of instructions actually completed, the number of cycles the processor is waiting for . You can also get a count of things like "number of memory reads", "number of cache misses", "number of TLB misses", "number of FPU instructions".

The next, more tricky part, is of course to try to fix any of these sort of issues, and as mentioned in another answer, programmers aren't always good at tweaking these sort of things - and it's certainly time consuming, not to mention that what works well on processor model X will not necessarily run fast on model Y (there were some tuning tricks for early Pentium 4 that works VERY badly on AMD processors - if on the other hand, you tune that code for AMD processors of that age, you get code that runs well on the same generation Intel processor too!)

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in the rdtsc x86 instruction, which reads a relative number of cycles.

See http://www.fftw.org/cycle.h for an implementation to read the counter in many compilers.

However, I'd suggest simply measuring using QueryPerformanceCounter. It is rare that the actual number of cycles is important, to tune code you typically only need to be able to compare relative time measurements, and rdtsc has many pitfalls (though probably not applicable to the situation you described):

- On multiprocessor systems, there is not a single coherent cycle counter value.
- Modern processors often adjust the frequency, changing the rate of change in time with respect to the rate of change in cycles.

Comment: Intel changed the specification of rdtsc years ago to say it returns real time, not cycles.